# sql schema design: mutable slot vs association table

Tags: sql, database-design, schema

I'm designing a schema for an as-yet-unspecified SQL database.  Consider the following:

- A network may contain many devices
- A device may be connected to zero or one networks

I see two plausible designs and I'm wondering about the pros and cons of each:

### The three table approach:

```
network
  network_id

device
  device_id

connection
  network_id
  device_id
```

The advantage of the three table approach is that it's easy to add state information to the connection (e.g. time of connection, port number, etc).  The disadvantage is that it suggests that one device may connect to multiple networks (a HABTM relationship), even though a device may only connect to one network at a time.

### The two-table approach:

```
network
  network_id

device
  device_id
  network_id (may be null if not connected)
```

The advantage of the two table approach is that it enforces the "connect to zero or one" network semantics.  The disadvantage is that the device itself becomes mutable, even though (logically speaking) the device isn't intrinsically changed simply by joining a network.

### ...

Despite the implicit HABTM nature of the three-table approach, I'm inclined to go that way and use higher level code to enforce the "instrument can only join one network" rule.

Does my reasoning pass muster?

Comment: For the three table solution, did you consider `primary key (network_id, device_id), unique (device_id)` ?

Comment: @mike: That doesn't really make sense. Declaring device_id unique means that { device_id } is a key, which in turn implies that { network_id, device_id } is a proper superkey (a proper superset of a key), i.e. not a key. SQL will let you declare a superkey as a key, but conceptually, it's wrong.

Comment: @JonHeggland: I'm not putting forward a solution. (I'd do that in an answer, not in a comment.) I'm asking a leading question. I think the OP is designing a Rails application, not designing a database.

Comment: @mike: I see. Then I apologise for ruining your Socratic dialogue. Out of curiosity, what is the relevance of Rails?

Comment: This is a one-to-many relationship (one network - many devices) and you just model it in the database as such. The most natural way to do it is the two-table approach that you have already described, or you can "force" it onto the three-table design as [Jon Heggland described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057330/533120). What exactly is the concern with modifying `network_id`? Why do you think that would be a problem?

Comment: This is not a Rails app (but my thinking has been conditioned by past work in Rails).  A "connection" between a device and network is likely to carry additional info that logically doesn't belong in the device itself.

Comment: @JonHeggland: "HABTM" is Rails jargon, not database designer jargon. Rails devs don't think like database designers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `device_id` as key for the connection table. That will limit each device to at most one network.